# How to find a Docker image on Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, kitematic

I am new to Docker. Using Kitematic, how can I setup a Docker container containing the following?

`Apache`, `Memcached`, `MySQL`, `Nginx`, `PHP FPM`

Should I find one single image with all these? If so, how do I find that on [https://hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=php&type=image)? It doesn't seem possible to filter by above requirements.

Or should I install these as separate containers?

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk Not sure what that means. With Kitematic I only have a create button for each image.

Comment: It is not advised to put them toghther, so there shall be few images. If you insist on doing this, you'd better write your own dockerfile for security considerations.

Comment: i don't know what is Kitematic... they don't have an predefined image that they made? and why need both Apache and Nginx ? 
any way... look at the docker-compose documentation and learn how to configure a group of contaners that can talk one to another in the same network https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: "It doesn't seem possible to filter by above requirements." <- the most frustrating thing about DockerHub.  I want to filter by "Linux" and "JDK" and "14", but that's impossible.  Amazes me that Docker has come as far as it has with this poor attention to UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bart,

I don't know anything about kitematic but I can give you some general information though to clear things up.

General concensus is to run only a single process per container. There are lot's of discussions and information around why this would be good or bad, one such discussion for example: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container.

That said, these are the images I would choose for an environment with the software you described above:

- Memcache: https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached
- MySql: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql
- Nginx: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx
- PHP FPM: https://hub.docker.com/_/php

How do I get these images? I go to hub.docker.com and search for the software I want, I then start with the official images and see if they suite my needs. If they do, great! Otherwise, I would look for non-official images and eventually if I don't find what I want I will extend the existing images by creating a custom image, based on one from hub.docker.com

Some more explanation about the last one, PHP. PHP is distributed with multiple tags. By going to the docker hub page ('description'-tab) you can see the supported tags. Clicking the tag you are interested in will lead you to a github repo where the Dockerfile is hosted. This file contains the commands, used to construct the image you are researching. You can check all the tags to see which one installs the software you need. For example, there are PHP tags where apache is installed (i.e. 7-apache) and there are tags where FPM is installed (i.e. 7-fpm).

Hope this will help you with the research about what images to use!

Comment: Bedankt Stijn! (Amplexor?).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run those images within the same docker network, tough a [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) (and is associated [`docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#your-first-docker-composeyml-file)) such as [this one](https://github.com/ipanardian/docker-php-nginx-mysql-memcached/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

The docker-compose support in Kinematic UI though... is still an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/137).

Answer (score 1):

you cant find all of these containers as one image.. all you can do is create a `docker-compose` file and add all those independent images into the compose file.

This way you can handle all your containers as a service in a single with there dependencies too..

For further info refer to https://docs.docker.com/compose/